# Vue.Js same GSAP animation for similar button, wreck my page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, hover, gsap

i'm struggling with something that seem simple but can succeed it without bugs.

I have 2 buttons in my Nav and i would like to make a nice GSAP animation (this one on code below is just for testing), so i made a gsap animation with Hover and mouseleave
and the event associated.
But sometimes it wrap all my pages on the left as if i selected the Body or something like that and apply my animation.

I'm using the event and i saw that might not be the best solution.

I would like to have one animation and be able to select safely my item
if anyone have ideas :)

**my templates**

```
<template>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header__logo">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}">
          <img :src="require('@/assets/Logo150.png')" alt="logo" /> 
        </router-link>
      </div>
      <div class="header__auth">
        <div class="header__auth__register circleAnimation" @mouseover="authHover" @mouseleave="authHoverLeave">
          <span>inscription</span>
          <div class="circle">
            <svg width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="the path" fill="#FCA311"/>
            </svg>            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header__auth__login circleAnimation" @mouseover="authHover" @mouseleave="authHoverLeave">
          <span>connexion</span>
          <div class="circle">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="the path" fill="#FCA311"/>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
</template>
```

**My JS**

```
<script>
import { gsap } from 'gsap';

export default {
  name: 'Header',
  data() {
      return {
        tl: gsap.timeline()
      }
    },
  mounted: function() {
    
    
    
  },
  methods: {
    authHover(event) {
      console.log('EVENT :' , event.relatedTarget)

      this.tl
      .to(event.relatedTarget, { width: '150px'})
      .to(event.relatedTarget.children[1], { autoAlpha: 1})

    },

    authHoverLeave(event) {
      console.log(event)
      this.tl.reverse();
    }
  }
  
}
</script>
```

example of what i get as result sometimes :[example of my bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBNAW.jpg)

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i tried to make the simplier possible, what could be more minimal ?

Comment: You're much more likely to get an answer if you provide a demo using something like CodePen or CodeSandbox that displays the issue

Comment: i would like to say that the bug is there cause i use the Hover event and it is not a good way to do it apparently ...
so i get that the bug come from there but i cant find a way to do what i want to do, 
1 GSAP animation for 2 similar buttons and be able to focus the one i really hover